# Use @Html.Actionlink Linktext string as input parameter into action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use the string in "linktext" and pass it as a parameter into @Html.ActionLink. The reason I want to do this is to retrieve an object from my model

Example code in razor view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("One","MyAction","MyController",myDictionary[<myLinktextString>],null)
```

Basically I want myLinktextString to be "One" when I click the actionlink.

Comment: once the view renders the helpers are no longer there and you are left with a tags.  If you want to change your link to pass different parameters dynamically you will need to do that with jquery

Comment: Could you give me an idea of how to do it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

an example with a text field and a button click would be something like this

```
<input type="text" class="linkText" />
<input type="button" class="redirectLink" value="Redirect" />
```

in your script you would have

```
$('.redirectLink').on('click', function(){
    var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { text = "0000" }';
    url = url.replace("0000", $(".linkText").val());
    window.location = url;
});
```

on the button click it will take the value of the text box and add it to a link and in this example redirect the user to that page.  Let me know if you have any questions.